# Is the form closed?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

> $S$ is an n dimensional unit sphere such that $S^n=(x\in \Bbb R^{n+1}: |x|=1)$ with some fixed orientation and $\omega$ is a volume form on $S$. Prove that $\omega$ is closed. Prove that $\omega$ is not exact

I really do not know how to do these two proofs. Can someone please please help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\omega = \star(1)$ so by definition of the exterior derivative one has $d\omega = 0$.

Comment: @Joelafrite what does that star mean? Can you please give a methodological answer?

Comment: An $n$-form on an $n$-dimensional manifold is automatically closed.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Why is that the case?

Comment: Because a $d\omega$ is an $n+1$ form on an $n$-manifold and so is necessarily zero.

Comment: @MarionCrane the "star" is the [Hodge star operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is just a consequence of Stokes' Theorem. First of all, all $n$-forms on an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ are closed, since $H^{n+1}(M) = 0$

In case this is not obvious: If $\beta$ is an $n+1$ form then for each $p \in M, \beta_p$ acts on $n+1$-elements of $T_pM$. Since $\dim T_pM = n$ then necessarily any $n+1$ vectors are linearly dependent, so $\beta_p = 0$.

On the other hand, if $M$ is a orientable closed manifold (compact without boundary), then a volume form cannot be exact. To see why this cannot be the case, if $\omega$ is a volume form then
$$ \int_M \omega >0$$
On the other hand, if $\omega = d\eta$ for some $n-1$ form eta, then by Stokes' theorem
$$ \int_M \omega = \int_M d\eta = \int_{\partial M} \eta = 0$$
since $\partial M = \emptyset$. This is a contradiction.